# How to get the value returned in the service to a controller in angular?

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I have  a service function like below.

```
app.service('UserService',['userFactory',function(userFactory)) {

  this.fetchAllUsers =function(){
  userFactory.getUsers(function(data){
  return data['body'];          //Return Array of objects         

  }),function(error){
            console.log("error while retrieving users")
  }
}
}])
```

I want to call this function in the controller and assign what ever the returned value to a variable. I tried out the following way

```
$scope.usersList=userService.fetchAllUsers();
```

But $scope.usersList is undefined. How can I get the returned value from the service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot return **asynchronous** call's result immediately, but can assign the result in `success(then) callback`.

**Note**: the `success/error callback` is deprecated in `angularjs1.6`, you have to use `then/catch` instead.

```
this.fetchAllUsers =function(){
    userFactory.getUsers(function(data){
        $scope.usersList = data['body'];         
    }),function(error){
        console.log("error while retrieving users")
    }
}
```

---

About how to define/call a service API with callback.

```
// in service
this.fetchAllUsers(callback) {
  userFactory.getUsers(function(data){
    callback(data);      
  }),function(error){
    console.log("error while retrieving users")
  }
}

// in controller
service.fetchAllUsers(function() {
  $scope.usersList = data['body'];   
});
```

Comment: What if you have to pass any value to the getUsers ?

Comment: @Rakeschand I think `getUsers` only have two params for callbacks, if you want to pass more, first todo is add additional parameter at definition of `getUsers`.

Comment: Yes exactly, what I am asking is what if there are two params as id, password then how would be the syntax look like in controller according to your style of code

Comment: @Pengyy but we can't use $scope in service right? this.fetchAllUsers() is defined in the service.

Comment: @spcd no, this is callback of asynchronous call in `userFactory.getUsers`. it's ok to do this.

Comment: @Pengyy But, i don't want to write this.fetchAllUsers() inside my controller. It is already declared in the service called "UserService" So, i wanna access it from the service without rewriting it.

Comment: @Pengyy I can't write fetachUsers method in myservice. It gives an erro saying unterminated statement. So, i wrote it like this.
            this.fetchAllUsers=function(callback) {
                    userFactory.getUsers(function(data){
                    callback(data);
                }),function(error){
                    console.log("error while retrieving users")
                }
            }
Then it says  callback is not a function . Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: @spcd how did you called `fetchAllUsers `? is it same with example I provided?

Comment: @Pengyy Yes, But I added data as a parameter inside the function.Otherwise it says data is not defined. But i don't get values for userList

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't [**inject**](http://HttpService%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.get('/Company/'%20+%20$cookies.get('department')%20+%20'/MaterialNo/GetMax')) your service in your controller.

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'userService', function($scope, userService) {
   $scope.usersList = userService.fetchAllUsers(); 
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it in controller.

I am assuming you have a service defined with name `'userFactory'`

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'userFactory', function($scope, userFactory) {
   $scope.fetchAllUsers = function() {
      userFactory.getUsers().then(function(response) {
          $scope.userlist = data;
      }, function() {});
    }
}]);
```

Don't use `$scope and this` both at the same time in controller. Use one of them. And call the service method `getUsers`. and get the result in success callback defined as `then`.

Comment: I don't want to declare the same $scope.fetchAllUsers() inside controller. It has already defined in a service called UserService. So, how can i access the function written in that service?